# Are there any new python library support systemd functionality other than DBUS

Tags: python, systemd

I would like to implement the **systemd** functionality from python script. Start and stop the services in Linux machine from python script using third party library.

```
e.g: sudo systemctl start application.service
```

I know there is a library which support the **systemd** kind of functionality, i.e DBUS

```
import dbus
sysbus = dbus.SystemBus()
```

But, I am looking for an best library other than dbus. Any ideas...

Comment: Any information regarding the above question.

Comment: A library could implement socket activation and say that it "supports systemd functionality", or support calling `systemctl` commands via the `subprocess.Popen` and say that it "supports systemd functionality", or support the `SD_NOTIFY` socket to provide detailed information on service status to the supervision daemon that started it and say that it "supports systemd functionality". This question is too broad to be useful -- one can't reasonably say whether a library does or doesn't do what you're looking for without considerably more details on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Moreover, we don't allow library recommendation questions here. See #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes there is `pystemd`

https://github.com/facebookincubator/pystemd

the tl;dr; ussage is

```
with Unit(b'postfix.service') as service:
    service.Unit.Start('replace')
```

also provides nice interface to `pystemd.run` and `sd_notify`

readme and _docs folder have a lot of code examples... feel free to ask anithing

Comment: If this answer is responsive, then the question is off-topic. See #4 in the "Some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ("*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*"), and note the bullet regarding questions which "*...are not about programming as defined in the help center*" in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).